# How to toggle the focus of an input using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, focus

I have been trying to make this thing that focuses an input inside it when its outer div is clicked. I really hope this is not a duplicate as I have searched everywhere and not found an answer to this. I am at risk of being blocked so I hope no one flags this as a duplicate.

Here is the code below, it works with focusing the input, but when it has to unfocus it does not seem to work.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var drop = document.getElementsByClassName("datadrop");
  var drops = document.getElementsByClassName("datadrop").length;

  for (x = 0; x < drops; x++) {
    var input = document.getElementById(drop[x].getAttribute("input"));
    drop[x].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      clicked = 0
      if (this == document.activeElement) {
        input.blur();
      } else {
        input.focus();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.datadrop {
  padding: 7.5px;
  width: 85px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.datadrop .drop {
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.datadrop .item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.datadrop .item:hover {
  background-color: #F1F3F4;
}

.datadrop .divider {
  padding: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

.datadrop .divider:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.datadrop input {
  width: 60px;
  color: black;
}

.datadrop:hover {
  background-color: #F1F3F4;
  color: #5F6368;
}

.datadrop .click {
  color: #5F6368;
}

.datadrop input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.datadrop input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div datadrop="scale" input="scales" class="datadrop">
  <input type="text" id="scales" value="100%"> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down click"></i>
  <div class="drop" id="scale">
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item divider">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
  </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

I hope someone has an answer to this using only JavaScript, and I hope no one flags this as a duplicate, as I am trying to not do duplicates.

Comment: It looks like the code works as it is? What exactly are you expecting the code to do? Notice that focus is not the same as hover.

Comment: I am expecting it to unfocus as soon as I re-click it, I have looked up toggling focus but all of the other answers require me to use jQuery.

Comment: There's a lot going on in the script. Whenever it creates more than a single event listener, `input` variable goes to haywire. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1169519

Comment: Do you by any chance know how I can resolve this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @topsoftwarepro check my answer, I have commented out my changes in it.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh thanks so much for your answer it works as well, but I found that one of the other answers addressed my problem the best, this is because I forgot to mention that I was going to use multiple of these, and your code only works for one of them. Still I appreciate your help and I have upvoted your answer as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your snippet.
you used a loop so i supposed that you want to have multiple inputs.
By the way, be careful the  element does't have a "input" attribute. I tried to follow the logic of your code so  i replaced the "input" -wrong- attribute with a data-input attribute.

I used two flags to check if the input is selected: "inputIsSelected" and "selectedDrop"

if inputIsSelected and clicked on same parent blur
if inputnotSelected and same parent focus
if parent changes then set the inputIsSelected to false

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var drop = document.getElementsByClassName("datadrop");
  var drops = document.getElementsByClassName("datadrop").length;
  let selectedDrop = null // a flag the clicked drop
  let inputIsSelected = false;
  console.log({drops})
  var x;  

  
  for (x = 0; x < drops; x++) {
    //var input = document.getElementById(drop[x].getAttribute("input"));
    
    let inputId = drop[x].dataset.input; //select inputId using a data-* attribute
 
    let input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    
    drop[x].onclick = function(e) {
       
      e.preventDefault();
      clicked = 0
      
      if(this!==selectedDrop){
       selectedDrop = this;
       inputIsSelected = false;
      }
      
      if(!inputIsSelected){
      input.focus();
      inputIsSelected=true;
      }else{
      inputIsSelected=false;
      input.blur()
      }
      
       
      
      
     
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.datadrop {
  padding: 7.5px;
  width: 85px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.datadrop .drop {
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.datadrop .item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.datadrop .item:hover {
  background-color: #F1F3F4;
}

.datadrop .divider {
  padding: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

.datadrop .divider:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.datadrop input {
  width: 60px;
  color: black;
}

.datadrop:hover {
  background-color: #F1F3F4;
  color: #5F6368;
}

.datadrop .click {
  color: #5F6368;
}

.datadrop input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.datadrop input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div datadrop="scale" data-input="scales-1" class="datadrop">
  <input type="text" id="scales-1" value="100%"> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down click"></i>
  <div class="drop" id="scale">
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item divider">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div datadrop="scale" data-input="scales-2" class="datadrop">
  <input type="text" id="scales-2" value="100%"> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down click"></i>
  <div class="drop" id="scale">
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item divider">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
  </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var drop = document.getElementsByClassName("datadrop");
  var drops = document.getElementsByClassName("datadrop").length;
  var focus_array = []; // lets log each focus and blur in this array
  
  for (x = 0; x < drops; x++) {
    var input = document.getElementById(drop[x].getAttribute("input"));
    drop[x].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      clicked = 0
      if (focus_array[x]) { // just check focus array 
        input.blur();
        focus_array[x]=0; //update focus array for blur
      } else {
        input.focus();
        focus_array[x]=1; //update focus array for focus
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.datadrop {
  padding: 7.5px;
  width: 85px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.datadrop .drop {
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.datadrop .item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.datadrop .item:hover {
  background-color: #F1F3F4;
}

.datadrop .divider {
  padding: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

.datadrop .divider:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.datadrop input {
  width: 60px;
  color: black;
}

.datadrop:hover {
  background-color: #F1F3F4;
  color: #5F6368;
}

.datadrop .click {
  color: #5F6368;
}

.datadrop input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.datadrop input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div datadrop="scale" input="scales" class="datadrop">
  <input type="text" id="scales" value="100%"> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down click"></i>
  <div class="drop" id="scale">
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item divider">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
    <div class="item">Fit</div>
  </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of the input based on the value of the keyboard input without giving the input focus, you can do this.

```
let element = document.getElementById("scales");

window.addEventListener("keydown", function () {

     element.value = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

})
```